# How to extract partial text from href using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's my code:

for item in data:

```
print(item.find_all('td')[2].find('a'))
print(item.find('span').text.strip())
print(item.find_all('td')[3].text)
print(item.find_all('td')[2].find(target="_blank").string.strip())
```

It prints this text below.

```
<a href="argument_transcripts/2016/16-399_3f14.pdf" 
id="ctl00_ctl00_MainEditable_mainContent_rptTranscript_ctl01_hypFile" 
target="_blank">16-399. </a>

Perry v. Merit Systems Protection Bd.

04/17/17

16-399.
```

All I want from the href tag is this part: `16-399_3f14`

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What kinds of things have you tried? `re` module provides powerful tools for extracting substrings from strings, however this case is simple enough you can probably do it with a couple calls to `str.split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the find_all to pull the the anchor elements that have the href attribute and then parse the href values for the information that you are looking for.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="argument_transcripts/2016/16-399_3f14.pdf" 
id="ctl00_ctl00_MainEditable_mainContent_rptTranscript_ctl01_hypFile" 
target="_blank">16-399. </a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    url = a['href'].split('/')
    print url[-1]
```

This should output the the string you are looking for.

```
16-399_3f14.pdf
```